# Do this in a single pass?

Tags: ruby

```
while(i < bArray.length)
  if(aArray.include?(bArray[i]) == false) then
    return false
  end
  i+=1
end
```

I've written the above but I find it to be ugly and bloated. There must be a clean cut way to do this in a single statement.. but how?

Comment: For clarity and consistency, perhaps also write out the expected behavior in English. This should help with "matching" up alternative approaches below. For instance, the exact final result of `i` (which appear to just be a temporary variable) may be important. Or it may not. Alternatively, the input may be expected to diverge early (if it does). Or it may not. The added detail (e.g. not "do this") can also be promoted to the question title to create a better post.

Comment: In Ruby, you usually use `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
while i < bArray.length
  return false unless aArray.include?(bArray[i])

  i += 1
end
```

Here's a one-liner that I think should be equivalent:

```
bArray.all? { |item| aArray.include?(item) }
```

Comment: left out the `return` sorry. I'm returning false if the char isn't there.

Comment: It's always a good sign if multiple come up with the same solution at the same time. It's usually either a pretty good or a pretty subtly wrong solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to find out if aArray contains all the elements of bArray.

```
aArray = %w[a b c d]
bArray = %w[a b c z]

(bArray - aArray).empty? # => false
```

I looked at the original code closer and it's got a logic bomb ticking:

```
def cmp_array(aArray, bArray)
  i = 0
  while (i < bArray.length)
    if (aArray.include?(bArray[i]) == false) then
      return false
    end
    i += 1
  end
end

def cmp_array2(a, b)
  (b - a).empty?
end

cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c   ]) # => nil
cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ c b a   ]) # => nil
cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b     ]) # => nil
cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c d ]) # => false
cmp_array( %w[ a b   ], %w[ a b c   ]) # => false

cmp_array2( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c   ]) # => true
cmp_array2( %w[ a b c ], %w[ c b a   ]) # => true
cmp_array2( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b     ]) # => true
cmp_array2( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c d ]) # => false
cmp_array2( %w[ a b   ], %w[ a b c   ]) # => false
```

I had to add the `i = 0` initializer otherwise Ruby complained about the uninitialized variable.

Notice that `cmp_array` returns either nil or false, forcing an additional test for `nil?` or `false?` to do something useful.

```
if (cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c   ]).nil?) ...
```

or:

```
if (cmp_array( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c d ]).false?) ...
```

compared to:

```
if (cmp_array2( %w[ a b c ], %w[ a b c   ])) ...
```

which consistently returns true/false.

Answer (score 4):

```
bArray.all?(&aArray.method(:include?))
```